# When do you need a Google Maps API Key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following [Google's Example - Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) I was able to make a very simple map to get myself started. I haven't signed up for an API Key though.

Tutorials I've read such as [Tutsplus - Getting creative with the Google Maps API](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-creative-with-the-google-maps-api--webdesign-13380) says it should be the first step.

That I should have a line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE&sensor=true"></script>`

But at least in this initial example from Google it works just fine with:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>`

I read:

- [Google Map API Issue. Using without API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254840/google-map-api-issue-using-without-api-key)
- [Google Map needs an API or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695862/google-map-needs-an-api-or-not)

But they don't really answer my more generalized question. When is it needed that I signup for the API Key? What limitations do I face by not signing up and just using the `..js?v=3.exp` instead? Is there some other thing I should be using... one of those two SO questions mentions `...maps/api/js?sensor=false` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an API key but it allows you to monitor your application. Also you'll need an API key if you want to take a license.

Source : https://developers.google.com/maps/signup